# Differentiate between Django dev server and apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

easy question:

In my settings file, I want to set a constant depending on whether I am running from the dev server or Apache.
Any elegant way of doing this?

I am running with mod_wsgi

Comment: If I understand correctly you can use DEBUG, DEBUG should be True in dev and False in production

Comment: What for do you want this constant ? I mean, if you run on dev server the "entry point" is django manage.py script, else the "entry point" is Apache process through reading your wsgi.py file. You cannot use this variable to discriminate what server to launch from inside Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
try:
    from mod_wsgi import version as MOD_WSGI_VERSION
except ImportError:
    MOD_WSGI_VERSION = None

if MOD_WSGI_VERSION:
    ... running mod_wsgi
```